# Strings/Numbers between two characters repeat multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a paragraph where two Strings come multiple times, I want to take the number between them, all the time it occurs. PFB the STRING.

```
Str1 = <Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>
Str2 = </Expression>

<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>1234</Expression>
absdf
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>4321</Expression>
%#$%$dfs
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>28320</Expression>
```

Expected output:

```
1234
4321
28320
```

I have tried the below code, but not sure how to fit this in some loop.

```
DECLARE @expr_body nvarchar(max)
SET @expr_body = '<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>1234</Expression>
absdf
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>4321</Expression>
%#$%$dfs
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>28320</Expression>
' 

select REPLACE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(@expr_body, CHARINDEX('literalValueType="System.String" name=>', @expr_body), LEN(@expr_body)),43),
'literalValueType="System.String" name=>','')
```

Comment: Honestly, SQL's forté is *not* string manipulation. If you can do this in something else, you'd likely be better off. If the above were valid XML, however, then this would be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu , Yes I can get this in XML, but no experience in that area.
I would really appreciate any helpful guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @expr_body nvarchar(max)
SET @expr_body = '<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>1234</Expression>
absdf
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>4321</Expression>
%#$%$dfs
<Expression type="Dell.DNC.Expressions.LiteralExpression" key="ProductPicker" literalValueType="System.String" name=>28320</Expression>
';

select t.n.value('.', 'int')
from 
(
select try_cast(replace(@expr_body, N'name=>', N'>') as xml) as trycastxml
) as src
cross apply src.trycastxml.nodes('/Expression') as t(n);
```